# How do I read a structure from a Memory/Pointer object in JNA?

Tags: java, pointers, struct, jna

I've been searching for an hour and still haven't found a way to do this. How do I read a structure from a memory/pointer object?
I don't see any methods in Pointer to read a structure, and the only methods of Structure that read from memory are protected.
I am trying to use a windows function that takes a pointer to a malloc'd structure array to store PHYSICAL_MONITOR's, which is why I need to do this.

Comment: Why did you tag this [c]?

Comment: Because I'm trying to read a c struct.

Comment: Should I remove the c tag?

Comment: Probably, yes. Could you post some code and give more details on what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

`Structure` defines a `Pointer`-based constructor.

```
class MyStructure extends Structure {
    public MyStructure() { 
    } 
    public MyStructure(Pointer p) { 
        super(p);
        read();
    }
```

See [the JavaDoc for `Structure`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) for the available options to control how/when Java fields are synched from native memory.